# PHP - check to see if input name start with specific name

Tags: php

I have several input fields for uploading files:

```
<input type=file name=logo />
<input type=file name=userfile />
<input type=file name=userfile1 />
.
.
.
<input type=file name=top />
<input type=file name=bottom />
```

Every file needs to be treated in some different way. How can I check if `$_FILES` starts, for example, with **userfile**?

Comment: if($_FILES['name'] = "userfile" DO THIS else DO THAT

Comment: print_r($_FILES) will show you the values you have to work with

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have mroe userfiles you can change your html marqup to

```
<input type=file name=userfile[1] />
<input type=file name=userfile[2] />
```

And then in PHP

```
foreach($_FILES['userfile'] as $i => $file) {
    processing
}
```

Othervise you can check if name starts with expected string (http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
<?
    if(substr($inputName, 0, 7) === "userfile")
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The examples given here might help you http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_FILES as $name => $file) {
    switch ($name) {
        case 'userfile' :
            ...
        case ... 
    }

    // or:

    if (substr($file, 0, 6) == 'userfile') {
        ...
    }
}
```

***BUT***, why do the `foreach..switch` if you can simply do:

```
echo $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
// do something with $_FILES['userfile']...

echo $_FILES['userfile1']['name'];
// do something with $_FILES['userfile1']...
```

Answer (score 0):

if ($_FILES['name'] == 'userfile') { /*code here*/} else {/*code here*/}  ?

I didn't test it, but I think it should work.